# How to get data from file_get_contents with grep.?

Tags: php, exec, file-get-contents

How to get file contents with grep.My code is like below i want all data matching string.I use exec command.

```
<?php
  $file = file_get_contents('nn.txt', true);
  $test=exec(' "$file" |grep rtcbiz',$sip);
  echo $test;
  ?>
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to use `exec` and `grep`?

Comment: @vitozev yes.Is there any alternative to do this?

Comment: sh: nn.txt: command not found

Comment: $text = \`grep rtcbiz nn.txt\`;  (use backticks)

Comment: @user2182349 It works.

Comment: I want this using exec